# Python Email Package with HTML

Tags: python, html, email, smtp

I'm looking for a solution to this problem: send email through SMTP with HTML in it. I'm following the doc here https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html and here https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html, but cannot find a workaround to integrate HTML to add the image part:

```
asparagus_cid = make_msgid()
msg.add_alternative("""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <p>Salut!</p>
   <p>Cela ressemble à un excellent
     <a href="http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718">
        recipie
    </a> déjeuner.
</p>
<img src="cid:{asparagus_cid}" />
</body>
</html>
""".format(asparagus_cid=asparagus_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')

with open("roasted-asparagus.jpg", 'rb') as img:
     msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'jpeg',
                                 cid=asparagus_cid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit :
To insert a `python object`, you may use `f-string`s. They're non-cumbersome and smoothly self-attaching to any string object.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage

object_to_be_inserted = "love"

message = EmailMessage()
message.add_alternative(f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    {object_to_be_inserted}

  </body>
</html>
""", subtype="html")
```

```
print(message)
```

```
[output]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============1697891563109361365=="

--===============1697891563109361365==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    love
  </body>
</html>
--===============1697891563109361365==--
```

======================================================
Old answer :
It is possible to send an Email with html using an instance of the `EmailMessage`class. The subtype parameter permits you to change the format of the message from plain text to, among other formats, html.

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage #This class has all you need to constitute an email message

#Initiate an instance of EmailMessage
message = EmailMessage()

message['subject'] = "The email subject"
message['From'] = 'your@address.com'
message['To'] = 'recipient@address.com'

#Now for the message body
message.set_content('A plain text fallback')
message.add_alternative("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
""", subtype='html')

#Then on with your endeavour as you must've seen in the documentation.
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('server_address', <port_no>) as smtp:
    smtp.login('address', 'password')
    smtp.send_message(message)
```

Now, for the image. You can add it inside the html body as if you would in a static web page.

Comment: I'd like to have the possibility to modify some tags in HTML text as per the image part

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Please be more specific.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't understand your problem from the get-go. I think I get what you mean, now. Check out the edit : You can insert object easily, in a readable manner with `f-string`s

Comment: Yes I used f-string as well but apparently the problem is in HTML code

Comment: Are you trying to add an image path so the an image gets displayed?

Comment: Yes, both text and image

Comment: Can you please update your question to convey the appropriate problem you're having so I can update my answer accordingly ?  
Also, please do post the code for `make_msgid()`.

Comment: For the text I use f-strings for the image part cannot upload the image even with make_msgid()

Comment: with open ('path/to/image.png', 'rb') as img: msg.get_payload()[0].add_related(img.read(),'image','png',cid=id_img)

Comment: It appears as if it cannot load the image

Comment: the user receives "the linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location"

Comment: The images are saved locally

Comment: Please update your question with the new info, and make sure it's readable.   
So that  
[1] a better versed user can answer you.  
[2] a future user who encounters a similar problem can relate and benefit from the answer. Thank you ( :

Comment: The infos are the same and the issue as well; upload images into HTML email using python Email module

Comment: It's a "we live in a society" kind of request. Please update your question with the appropriate infos. Otherwise, you're welcome to keep investigating the issue on your own.

Comment: edited, embedding the image into HTML is the problem